# Logarithmic space difference between deterministic and non-deterministic algorithms

Tags: algorithms, space-complexity, nondeterminism

I had an interview today, and the interviewer has told me about a theorem (of someone called Hill- or Hell-something) which states that for a non-deterministic algorithm there exists a deterministic algorithm of some time complexity and a space complexity of no more than the original space complexity times log(n).

I am looking for that theorem (couldn't find it on Google). Thanks!

Comment: [Savitch's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch's_theorem)?

Comment: @PratikDeoghare it seems similar, but I'm quite certain that that's not it.

Comment: $\mathsf{NSpace}(f(n)) \subseteq \mathsf{DSpace(f^2(n))}$ and nothing better is known (AFAIK).

Comment: note that if $f(n)=\lg n$, then $f^2(n)=\lg n \times \lg n$.

Comment: See this question http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2426/612.

Comment: What if f(n)=1 ? Is there some theorem regarding that?

Comment: constant amount of space is trivial, it is just a regular language.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks. I still wonder what he was talking about...

Comment: @PratikDeoghare Post as an answer?

Comment: Savitch's theorem is for $f(n)\geq \log \ n$. What about $f(n) < \log \ n$?